# How can I dim the screen from Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, screen

Is it possible to dim the screen from Terminal, in a Mac with OS X Lion? Is there any command to do control brightness and volume?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it via an Applescript and run it as such:

Dimmer:

```
tell application "System Events"
        key code 144
end tell
```

Brighter:

```
tell application "System Events"
        key code 145
end tell
```

You can save these as .script files and then run them from the CLI like this:

```
osascript ~/Path/to/File
```

You may [refer to this](http://osxdaily.com/2019/08/14/change-screen-brightness-mac-terminal/).

You can also do it [this way](https://superuser.com/a/329729/90435), but that requires more setup.

Comment: Not working on Mac OS X 10.12.6.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on MacOS 10.14.

Comment: The key codes should be 144 and 145, respectively. See http://osxdaily.com/2019/08/14/change-screen-brightness-mac-terminal/

Answer (score 25):

You can install this command line tool from [github.com/nriley/brightness](https://github.com/nriley/brightness). The install is pretty easy if you have homebrew:

```
brew install brightness
```

And usage is straightforward:

- Set 100% brightness: `brightness 1`
- Set 50% brightness:
  `brightness 0.5`

Unfortunately it doesn't work for external monitors. See [Does Apple support DDC/CI for  3rd party displays via Apple's Thunderbolt to DVI adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61045/does-apple-support-ddc-ci-for-3rd-party-displays-via-apples-thunderbolt-to-dvi) for background on why.

Comment: For me, these instructions installed a command called  `brightness`, not `screenbrightness`. Otherwise, this worked as described. Thanks!

Comment: I think it have to do with a github merge of projects. When that happened they updated the command to `brightness` (which someone in Community happily already fixed in the answer).

Comment: Note that the brightness Homebrew package is currently broken under macOS 10.13.  See https://github.com/nriley/brightness/issues/21.

Comment: *Does* work for my external LG Ultrafine™ 5K, but I think that's an exception as it implements extra APIs

Answer (score 9):

[image: screenshot]

I've created a node module for this that supports setting the brightness using the CLI. See https://github.com/kevva/brightness-cli.

```
npm install --global brightness-cli
```

And then simply just run `brightness` from your command line.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `$ brightness 100

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/brightness-cli/cli.js:3
const brightness = require('brightness');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

Comment: work for me but it does not tell at system level