# Command line brightness (Lion)

Tags: macos, command-line, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I dim the screen from Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/how-can-i-dim-the-screen-from-terminal)

Is there a command I can execute to modify screen brightness? Interested to see if the min/max are hardware or software controlled, and what can be done for quick brightness changing without an apple keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built in way to adjust brightness in Terminal.app.  However, several people have written programs which can do this.  You'd need to download the code/copy it and compile the program so you can run the utility from Terminal.  Here's an example on [mattdanger.net](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/)