# Set Brightness to Full on Boot (MacBook Pro)

Tags: applescript, screen, display

I frequently have the problem where my laptop's screen is too dim prior to login and I can barely tell where my account or the mouse is. Is there a way to set the brightness to maximum on boot before any user has logged in by using the equivalent of an init script?

I've seen some useful applescript snippets here ([How can I dim the screen from Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/how-can-i-dim-the-screen-from-terminal)) to adjust the brightness from the terminal, but I'm not confident these will work if no user is logged in.

edit:

creating an /etc/rc.local script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for i in {1 .. 1000}
do
    osascript /opt/utils/brighter.script
done
```

with an applescript script to brighten the screen

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 113
end tell
```

only makes the screen a little bit brighter (perhaps a quarter of the way) and it doesn't seem to make much difference what number is used in place of 1000.

edit:

Trying to use screenbrightness in my /etc/rc.local appears not to work either. I suspect that the initial login screen that loads immediately is shown before the init script is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Turn you screen fully bright. Open Terminal, type `nvram backlight-level`. Note the value. Create a logout hook to run `nvram backlight-level=<value>`. In my case the value was `%a0%06`.

If you run it interactively, you need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo nvram backlight-level='%a0%06'
```