# Is there any way to adjust Macbook brightness from 0% or 50% or 100% with a simple keyboard shortcut that can be used with Karabiner-Elements?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, karabiner

I'm looking for a solution to use just a simple keyboard shortcut to quickly toggle the brightness level from any percentage to 0% or any percentage to 50% or any percentage to 100%.

Comment: btw also any shell command would be great help

Comment: Have you seen https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127258/150109, does it work for you? Just bind that to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: yeah I've seen that @theonlygusti but it has lots of complication/limitations as I read on the Github repo

Comment: Did you try the `brightness` binar? Seems to do exactly what you need?

Comment: If you meant the thing @theonlygusti have mentioned. I'm not actually confident about the app/repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've tried to find any shell command or any simple solution but I couldn't find any simple shell command that I can put on my karabiner.json file. Although I found this `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'key code 144/145' -e ' end tell'` and I can use it like this way `echo; for i in $(seq 4); do osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'key code 144/145' -e ' end tell'; done`. But obviously it won't know the exact level and won't go to the exact level. Maybe I can just only use it to move quickly though the brightness level, like 4 dots.

However as everyone here commenting about a terminal based package called [Brightness](https://github.com/nriley/brightness). So I just tried it myself, altho I was cautious as there was bit warning bout this app on their GitHub and after installing it I also saw it's limitation as well. But nonetheless it is working for my machine.

As I hardly ever uses this function key for play pause rewind (use spacebar left right key for that) so I did put this way on my karabiner.json...

```
                {
                    "description": "f7 to 0% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f7"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"brightness 0\"' && sleep .5 && osascript -e 'quit app \"Terminal\"'"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f8 to 50% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f8"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"brightness .5\"' && sleep .5 && osascript -e 'quit app \"Terminal\"'"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f9 to 100% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f9"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"brightness 1\"' && sleep .5 && osascript -e 'quit app \"Terminal\"'"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

***Edit: After using some times I've noticed [Brightness](https://github.com/nriley/brightness) doesn't work properly (stopped working everytime the display goes to sleep). That's why I'm now using like this... (only goes to 0% or 100% but I think it's very simple & works for me)***

```
                {
                    "description": "f7 to 0% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f7"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "for i in $(seq 16); do osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'key code 145' -e ' end tell'; done"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f8 to down 50% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f8"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "for i in $(seq 8); do osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'key code 145' -e ' end tell'; done"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f9 to 100% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f9"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "for i in $(seq 16); do osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'key code 144' -e ' end tell'; done"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f3 to down 25% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f3"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "for i in $(seq 4); do osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'key code 145' -e ' end tell'; done"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "description": "f4 to up 25% brightnsess",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "f4"
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "shell_command": "for i in $(seq 4); do osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'key code 144' -e ' end tell'; done"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```